# Hibernate self-reference relationship and lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, jpa, lazy-loading

Before asking the question, here is the context of my problem:

I got a specific entity named 'Category', which have a property Category (a parent) and another property of type 'relatedEntity'.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="entityID")
    private RelatedEntity entity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentID")
    private Category parent;

    ...
}
```

So, as you can see, I've declared ManyToOne relationships for these properties, and also a lazy loading fetching strategy.

Now, I use this method inside a DAO object to get a list of Category:

```
public List<Category> getAll() {
    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Category.class);
    return (crit.list());
}
```

I got a specific service object which calls the DAO method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
    return (categoryDAO.getAll());
}
```

Nothing really extraordinary for the moment... Now, here come my unit tests:

```
@Test
public void testCategories() {

    List<Category> cat = service.getAllCategories();
    assertNotNull(cat);
    assertFalse(cat.isEmpty());

    for (Category c : cat) {

        try {
            assertNotNull(c.getEntity().getName());
            fail("Expected lazy init. on Category.Entity");
        }
        catch(LazyInitializationException ex) {
             //Exception is caught
        }

        try {
            assertNotNull(c.getParent().getName());
            //No exception
            fail("Expected lazy init. on Category.Parent");
        }
        catch(LazyInitializationException ex) {}
    }
}
```

After running the test, an exception is catched in the first try/catch block and the second fail is fired, saying that there is no LazyInitException on the parent property of the category.

So I can call

```
c.getParent().getParent().getName();
```

or

```
c.getParent().getParent().getParent().getName()
```

without any exception being raised.

I've set 'show_sql=true' in my configuration file, I can't see any supplementary request in my logs after calling the getter on the parent property, so there is no new request but the parent property is loaded.

Can somebody explain me why the parent property is not lazy?

EDIT:

I've updated my test case.

```
@Test(expected=LazyInitializationException.class)   
public void lazyCategoriesParentsList() {
    List<Category> cat = service.getAllCategories();

    assertNotNull(cat);
    assertFalse(cat.isEmpty());

    for (Category c : cat) {            
        assertNotNull(c.getParent().getName());     
    }       
}
```

And now the test is passing... Was it related to the access of the entity property (via c.getEntity()) in my previous test case?

Comment: You should _not_ catch Exceptions in a unit test and manually fail (or fail when no exception is thrown, as in your case), you should propagate the expected exception with `@Test(expected=LazyInitializationException.class)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try getting only one **Category** instead of loading them all ?

Indeed, when you are loading a **Category**, if hibernate can find its *parent* in the same **Session**, it will initialize it, even if *parent* is marked as lazy. As you are querying for all categories, it will find all the parents in the **Session** and initialize them.

Comment: Yep, seems to be a good answer, I've just tried with a single Category, and the LazyInitException is caught after calling the getter parent ! Wasn't aware of the behavior of Hibernate in that case, thanks ! Could there be a performance issue there as I can retrieve all the Categories and linked parents?

Comment: Well, I've updated my test case in reference to His comment and edited my question. My test being more atomic and focusing only on the parent property, the test is now passing and the parent is being loaded lazily. But I've no clues about the reason of the previous fail test.